# How Uber iOS App Updates the App UI without Pushing Update to App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have observed this a few times, if there is some offer or new ride option available, it reflects in the Uber iOS App directly. How they are able to make changes to the app directly, without pushing update to App Store?

Comment: Off the top of my head, they might be loading the UIResources from an independent server on runtime. That would provide them the flexibility to do so. I have never used uber so I wouldn't know exactly.

Comment: Can you share screenshots?

Comment: By the way, it is only possible if they have set code such that any type of offer, ride etc available will be displayed how dynamically in the app. App will ping server for new available services, and if any, it will be displayed right in front of user. I haven't too used Uber.. just giving you a concept.

Comment: as per my knowledge only that part which is change just because of they are using webview.

Answer (score 1):

They are using webviews and honestly you can set your code up on the backend to have "flags" to create UI changes on the front end without you updating the app.